# Calculate average time between two datetimes across all records?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

Each record has a `started_at` and `completed_at` datetime field. To calculate the time it took someone to start and complete is obviously easy.

But what I need to do is calculate an average time from start to complete for ALL records.

Ultimately want to be able to say "It takes, on average, X amount of time to start and complete."

I'm running Rails 3.0.6, in case there's some functionality already built in with that.

Also, it's a Postgresql database, but ideally this would work across other databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Pure SQL solution would be:

```
SELECT AVG(TotTime)
FROM (SELECT DateDiff(minute, started_at, completed_at) as 'TotTime'
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE <stuff>) as SubQuery
```

You can change the part in the `DateDiff` function to be whatever you need (hours, seconds, milliseconds, etc).

Comment: Is *`TotTime`* the time you spend being a little Tot running around in the garden? :)

Comment: Is DateDiff a general SQL function or should it work fine with PostgreSQL?

Comment: `DATEDIFF` is a SQL Server function.  You really should specify what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Yeah, definitely my bad on that. Just updated my post. Sorry about that.

Comment: Looks like in PostGres you can subtract the two dates and get an `INTERVAL` datatype that you can convert as needed.